# dask export dataframe to remote storage (S3)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, export-to-csv, dask

When using

```
dask_df.to_csv('s3://mybucket/mycsv.csv')
```

I get an error that I should install `s3fs`

I did install it in the workers (with `client.run()`) and still got the error.

So I installed s3fs locally in my machine, then it does works.
But does it means that the data is first sent to my machine and only then exported to S3? Instead of being only processed in the cluster?

Also I get `KilledWorker` errors. The export is made of two dask dataframes made by `dd.concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

> But does it means that the data is first sent to my machine and only then exported to S3? Instead of being only processed in the cluster?

No, it just means that your client process needs to also talk to S3 in order to set things up.

In general, the software environment on your workers and your client process should be the same.